# Разбить видео на кадры ffmpeg (bat скрипт, проблема в имени файла при сохранение)

Tags: bat, ffmpeg

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как написать bat скрипт для ffmpeg.
Мне нужно разбить 100 видео на кадры.

В папке файлы лежат в формате:

*/Видео_001/Кадры/Видео_001.mp4

/Видео_002/Кадры/Видео_002.mp4

/Видео_003/Кадры/Видео_003.mp4

/Script.bat*

**При разбивке скриншоты нужно поместить в папку, где лежит видео**.
Я сделал сделал такой скрипт:

```
@echo off

    for /r %%i in (*.mp4) do (
        ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf "select=not(mod(n\,35))" -vsync vfr "%%~dpni_img%03d.jpg"
    )
```

Но у меня создаётся по 1 скриншоту в каждой папке с именем
**НазваниеВидеоimgscript_mmpeg_video_to_photo.bat3d.jpg**

Создаётся 1 скриншот, выдаётся ошибка, что скриншот с таким именем есть и переходит к следующему видео. Вместо сотен скриншотов для каждого видео, получается по одному скриншоту.

У меня проблема в имени сохраняемых скриншотов. Нужна нумерация. Я понимаю, что мне нужно добавить **%03d** к имени сохраняемого файла, но как это сделать правильно (пытался по всякому уже много много раз) не соображу.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Судя по заголовку, проблема в разборке видео на кадры. Судя по тексту, проблема в сохранении. Так в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: ``$filename%03d.jpg``

Comment: Прошу прощение за заголовок. Проблема именно в сохранение файла.

Comment: Вашим способом получается 1 скриншот в корне, где лежит скрипт. Нумерация всё равно почему-то не идёт правильно. А задача, что бы скриншоты лежали в папке, где лежит видео.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg -i "%%i" -an -ss 5 -r 0.05 -vframes 100 -y "%db.jpg"

Comment: Спасибо за вариант! Но создаётся 1 скриншот рядом со скриптом (а не в папках, где лежат видео). А потом выдаёт ошибку: 

[image2 @ 00000000003ec9c0] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '
db.jpg'. Use '-frames:v 1' for a single image, or '-update' option, or use a pat
tern such as %03d within the filename.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение в другом месте. Что бы работал счётчик %03d в имени фотографии, нужно ставить 2 знака процента. При явном вызове команд в cmd пишется 1 знак %, а в скриптах нужно %%.

Мой рабочий вариант:

```
@echo off

for /r %%i in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%i" -an -ss 5 -r 0.05 -vframes 100 -y "%%~dpni_img%%03d.jpg" 
)
```

Отличия в имени.

Было:  `"%%~dpni_img%03d.jpg"`

Стало: `"%%~dpni_img%%03d.jpg"`